# Webforms: get original checked value of checkboxes

Tags: javascript

I have a checkboxlist on a webform and it is rendered as a table with input checkboxes, etc. I have many many other input controls on the form. I need to reset the checkboxes inside of the checkbox list control table to their original values from the postback. Given the following code:

```
console.clear();
jQuery("table[id*='ctrlAccountType']").find("[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
    var elem = this;
    var originalValue = elem.getAttribute("value");
    console.debug(originalValue);
});
```

I'm getting the value of the checkbox but not the original *checked* state before the user monkeyed with it and decided that 10 checkboxes were too many to remember. Using 'checked' instead of `value` gives me "checked" in the console for each checkbox (actually, I'm getting 9 checked and one null). How can I do this without using a reset button and resetting the entirety of the form and without a postback?

Comment: set the Original value in a `data-value` attribute. So you can load it from there. It's basically a backup.

Comment: I edited my question to clarify something and realized that the code is working correctly. However, I like your response. There's no need for me to do that this time but I'll certainly use that in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In editing my question, I came up with my answer. The code is working correctly. It is showing "checked" for each one that was originally checked and since "checked" is an attribute, if it's not checked, it's not there and is therefore null.